# Using ReactiveUI, Observables, SubscribeOn, and ObserveOn to display an output log in UI during a long-running process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, system.reactive

I have a WPF application that will launch a long-running task (60+ seconds) that uses a `System.Reactive.Subject<string>` to push status messages periodically. The idea was that I could then Subscribe to the observable from my ViewModel and have ReactiveUI automatically update my UI through a Data Binding. This all works fine except that the TextBox is not updating in real-time. It only updates after long-running task has completed. I presume this is because my UI thread is being blocked and cannot update.

Working under that assumption, my research suggested that I could put the subscription on a background thread using `SubscribeOn` and then push the notifications back to the UI thread using `ObserveOnDispatcher`. However, this still did not produce the results that I wanted -- the UI only updated after long-running task had returned.

Can anybody give me some insight on what I need to do to allow my Output log to update in real time? Below are the related pieces of code.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Output}" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10,0,10,10" x:Name="OutputTextBox" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Converter == null) return;
            _viewModel = new ConversionOutputWindowViewModel(Converter);
            DataContext = _viewModel;
            _viewModel.StartConversion(); // Long-running Task
            //_viewModel.StartSave();
            FinishButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
private string _output;

public string Output // Data bound in XAML
        {
            get { return _output; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _output, value); }
        }

public void StartConversion()
        {
            _edmxConverter.Convert(); // Long-running Task
        }

public ConversionOutputWindowViewModel(Utilities.Converters.EdmxConverter converter)
        {
            _edmxConverter = converter;
            _compositeDisposable.Add(_edmxConverter.Output
                                                   .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
                                                   .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                                                   .Subscribe(s => Output = Output += s));
            //_compositeDisposable.Add(_edmxConverter.Output.Subscribe(s => Output = Output += s));
        }
```

Long-Running Task Function:

```
public Subject<string> Output { get; }

Output = new Subject<string>(); //In ctor

private void PrintReplacement(XAttribute attribute, string oldValue, string newValue, int level, Verbosity minVerbosity = Verbosity.Informational)
        {
            if (Verbosity < minVerbosity) return;
            Output.OnNext($"{new string('\t', level)}{attribute.Name}: {oldValue} -> {newValue}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
```

Would it maybe help to wrap my Long-running Task function call inside an `await Task.Run`? I'm grasping at straws here. I don't have a very good working knowledge of .NET threading.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using subjects, so `.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)` does nothing. (Standard old drum beating) Don't use subjects.

Your long running process should be a method call that returns an `IObservable<T>` (instead of having a class that exposes a property). The `T` should be the status updates you want to receive. When the task is done, then you OnComplete. If the task fails, you OnError.

Ideally the method that returns the IObservable using Observable.Create to deifne the work that will need to be done.

```
public IObservable<string> Convert()
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(observer=>
    {
        //do stuff here.
        //Call observer.OnNext with status messages
        //When done call observer.OnCompleted()
    });
}
```

As you dont show what your long running task is I cant help anymore with the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is very interesting and probably really serves to display my very rudimentary understanding of Reactive. Would you mind expanding on why using Subjects is bad? My understanding was that a 'Subject<T>' was simply an object which provided standard implementations of both 'IObservable' and 'IObserver'. I wanted to use a Subject because I have a few "Print-" methods which are all calling 'Output.OnNext(s)'. I didn't realize that was important otherwise I would've included it in the question. I'm not sure how that pattern would work when using 'Observable.Create'